# Cassandra: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface

Tags: python, unicode, cassandra, prepared-statement

I try to use these both prepared statements in my django app:

```
READINGS = "SELECT * FROM readings"
READINGS_BY_USER_ID = "SELECT * FROM readings WHERE user_id=?"
```

I query against the db with:

```
def get_all(self):
    query = self.session.prepare(ps.ALL_READINGS)
    all_readings = self.session.execute(query)

    return all_readings

def get_all_by_user_id(self, user_id):
    query = self.session.prepare(ps.READINGS_BY_USER_ID)
    readings = self.session.execute(query, [user_id])

    return readings
```

The first of both works pretty well. But the second gives me:

```
ERROR 2015-07-08 09:42:56,634 | views::exception_handler 47 | ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {<Host: localhost data1>: TypeError("'unicode' does not have the buffer interface",)})
```

Can anyone tell me what happened here? I understand, that there must be a unicode string somewhere that does not have a buffer interface. But which string is meant? My prepared statement?

Here is the stacktrace in addition:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 448, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Workspace/project/Readings/views.py", line 36, in get_by_user_id
    readings = self.tr_dao.get_all_by_user_id(user_id)
  File "/Users/me/Workspace/project/Readings/dao.py", line 22, in get_all_by_user_id
    readings = self.session.execute(query, [user_id], timeout=60)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1405, in execute
    result = future.result(timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2967, in result
    raise self._final_exception
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are on python 2 this will probably fix it

```
def get_all_by_user_id(self, user_id):
    query = self.session.prepare(ps.READINGS_BY_USER_ID)
    readings = self.session.execute(query, [str(user_id)])
    return readings
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because your user_id is of type unicode. You can check it using

`type(user_id)`

If that is the case you should encode it to string:
`str(user_id)`

It will solve the issue.